# Reconcile channels with varying data acquisition frequencies

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation, reindex

My dataframe has 8 columns for 4 different *data* recorded as a function of *depth*. However, each channel came with a different acquisition frequency. I would like to reconcile all these 4 data using a common depth interval.

Interpolation with Scipy looked complex, so is there any easier method to, for example, apply the first *depth* (`'depth1'`) to all other *data*?

Here is a data sample:

```
df=pd.read_csv(file,sep='\t')
df
depth1  data1   depth2  data2   depth3  data3   depth4  data4
0   910.0   32.820  910 48.2    910.05  450.57  912.961414  -294.045478
1   910.1   33.610  911 48.2    910.20  1.14    922.966707  -447.780089
2   910.2   33.900  912 48.2    910.35  1.14    932.972000  -396.001844
3   910.3   34.190  913 48.4    910.50  1.43    942.976616  -391.830800
4   910.4   34.430  914 48.7    910.65  1.32    952.980427  -438.514022
5   910.5   34.670  915 48.9    910.80  1.54    962.984317  -679.421100
6   910.6   35.015  916 48.8    910.95  16.08   972.988514  -660.389044
7   910.7   35.360  917 49.0    911.10  8.16    982.993188  -671.841567
8   910.8   35.450  918 49.5    911.25  7.67    992.998200  -712.625933
9   910.9   35.540  919 49.4    911.40  8.86    1003.004001 -884.093533
10  911.0   35.825  920 49.5    911.55  8.70    1013.009802 -1124.780022
11  911.1   36.110  921 49.6    911.70  7.93    1023.015603 -1454.342144
```

Comment: `The result doesn't look good` Can you clarify what aspect of it is not good? One aspect of it stands out to me: `data3` has a ringing artifact from trying to fit data which is varying so much. One solution to that would be to use nearest interpolation, or linear interpolation. But that is just a guess, since I don't know your goal.

Comment: Thanks Nick, any other method other than interpolation?

Comment: If you had depth values that exactly matched each other, I would say that you could try a merge/join. Since you don't, anything you do will be interpolation of one kind or another.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In python pandas, how can I re-sample and interpolate a DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41493282/in-python-pandas-how-can-i-re-sample-and-interpolate-a-dataframe)

Comment: Thank you for the positive feedback. I meant to ask, why had you removed your code? It looked in line with SO guidelines to post code and problems encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method of choice will remain reindex - interpolate indeed and it is not that complex. You don't *have* to use Scipy for that (the code that you transiently posted) since Pandas already has some built-in capabilities. Here the example of channel `("depth2", "data2")` reindexed over the axis `"depth1"`:

**Craft the new index**

```
Idx1 = pd.Index(df.set_index('depth1').index) # new index for data2
Idx2 = pd.Index(df.set_index('depth2').index) # original data2 index

# Merge indexes depth1 and depth2
NewIdx = pd.Index(Idx2.union(Idx1), 
                  name = 'depth')
```

Output:

```
Index([910.0, 910.1, 910.2, 910.3, 910.4, 910.5, 910.6, 910.7, 910.8, 910.9,
       911.0, 911.1, 912.0, 913.0, 914.0, 915.0, 916.0, 917.0, 918.0, 919.0,
       920.0, 921.0],
      dtype='float64', name='depth')
```

**Operate the reindexing**

```
df2 = df[['depth2', 'data2']].set_index('depth2'    # the subset of df to be reindexed,
                     ).reindex(NewIdx               # reindexed, as a new dataframe
                     ).interpolate(method='linear') # gaps filled by interpolation
```

**Finally select interpolated data only**

> df2.loc[Idx1]

This will plot the results:

```
# Plot original and interpolated data separately:
_=plt.plot(df2.reindex(Idx2).index, 
           df2.reindex(Idx2).values,'+')
_=plt.plot(df2.reindex(Idx1).index, 
           df2.reindex(Idx1).values,'x')
_=plt.xlim(909.9, 912.1)
_=plt.xlabel('depth')
_=plt.ylabel('data')
plt.legend(['original data2','interpolated along depth1'])
```